# Filtering for Nested Property in Javascript/Lodash

Tags: javascript, filter, nested, lodash

I currently have data that looks like this:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Canada",
    "checked": true,
    "vacationSpots": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Toronto",
        "checked":false,
        "activities": [{
            "id": 1,
            "checked": false,
            "name": "Niagara Falls"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "France",
        "checked":true,
        "activities": [{
            "id": 2,
            "checked":true,
            "name": "Eiffel tower"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "US",
    "checked": true,
    "vacationSpots": [{
        "id": 3,
        "name": "California",
        "checked": true,
        "activities": [{
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Surfing",
            "checked":false
        }]
    }]
}]
```

I'm gathering the activities id's from activities which have checked set to true.

so the result looks something like this:

```
2
```

While I can get this, I have to go through 3 levels before I can access activities

```
  for (i = 0; i < country.length; i++){
    country = allAreas[i];
  ....
    for (j = 0; j < country.vacationSpots.length; j++){
  ....
        for (k = 0; k < vacationSpots.activities.length; k++){
```

(Search through country, then vacationSpots, then activities. Is there a way to filter this without traversing through each level? Is there a way to do this with Lodash?

Comment: Don't see a way to do this without using nested iterators. What does your current code look like?

Comment: @Phil The way I'm currently traversing through this is via three for loops, 1 to loop over each country, another to loop over the vacationSpots in each country and a final 1 to loop over the activities in each vacationspot.

Comment: I updated my code with a bit of my for loop snippet

Comment: If you want to go through an array to find something, you have to go through the array. If you want to go through a nested array to find something, you have to go through the nested array--one way or another.

Comment: can `activities` contain more than one element?

Comment: Your code is invalid. Missing comma after a couple of `checked` properties.

Comment: @torazaburo yes activities can contain more than 1 element.

Comment: Is it meant to be `vacationSpots` instead of `vactionSpots`?

Comment: @Phil My bad! It's vacationSpots,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the interest of providing an array of unique activity IDs for *checked* activities across your entire data set, assuming that any particular activity could potentially show up in more than one country / vacation spot, something like this should suffice

```js
let data = [{"id":1,"name":"Canada","checked":true,"vacationSpots":[{"id":1,"name":"Toronto","checked":false,"activities":[{"id":1,"checked":false,"name":"Niagara Falls"}]},{"id":2,"name":"France","checked":true,"activities":[{"id":2,"checked":true,"name":"Eiffel tower"}]}]},{"id":2,"name":"US","checked":true,"vacationSpots":[{"id":3,"name":"California","checked":true,"activities":[{"id":3,"name":"Surfing","checked":false}]}]}];

let activityMap = data.reduce((map, country) => {
    country.vacationSpots.forEach(vs => {
        vs.activities.forEach(activity => {
            if (activity.checked) {
                map[activity.id] = true;
            }
        });
    });
    return map;
}, Object.create(null));

let activities = Object.keys(activityMap).map(Number);
console.log(activities);
```